# Phoenix form validation check not showing up but non-null constraint from postgres

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework

When trying to build form validations my error shows up in the form when I use a username exceeding 20 char, but not when I enter nothing. I get a **violates non-null constraint** Postgres.Error view.

```
# user.ex
def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
  model
  |> cast(params, ~w(name username), [])
  |> validate_length(:username, min: 1, max: 20)
end
```

Which probably is because of the migration:

```
def change do
  create table(:users) do
    add :name, :string         
    add :username, :string, null: false
    add :password_hash, :string

    timestamps
  end

  create unique_index(:users, [:username])
end
```

Going through the Programming Phoenix book, which is unfortunately getting a little outdated, I can't find a quick solution to this problem.

Somehow the Postgres shouldn't come before the validation checks. Any idea on how to make this error go away?

Comment: Have you tried adding `validate_required([:username, :other_fields])` to your changeset pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't work, I assume you're using Phoenix 1.3, so try changing this code

```
def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
  model
  |> cast(params, ~w(name username), [])
  |> validate_length(:username, min: 1, max: 20)
end
```

With this:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
  model
  |> cast(params, ~w(name username))
  |> validate_required([:username])
  |> validate_length(:username, min: 1, max: 20)
end
```

You can check more details in documentation of [`Ecto.Changeset.validate_required/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_required/3).

Hope that helps!

Comment: i was just writing basically the exact thing 

Comment: That does do the trick, I have to be a little bit meticulous and note that now I (of course) get "can't be blank", while the book shows that the more fitting "should be at least 1 character(s)" is also possible. The `min:` part simply misses it's function here somehow.

Comment: Same difference of course, I suppose I could leave the extra line of code as is.